# Solve : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure

Tags: pyspark

Hi I am facing a problem related to pyspark, I use `df.show()` it still give me a result but when I use some function like `count()`, `groupby()` v..v it show me error, I think the reason is that 'df' is too large.

Please help me solve it. Thanks!

```
import datetime
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("box") \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "25g",conf) \
    .getOrCreate()

basepath = '/mnt/raw_data/play/log_stream/playstats_v100/topic=play_map_play_vod'
path = ['/mnt/raw_data/play/log_stream/playstats_v100/topic=play_map_play_vod/date=2021-01*']
df = spark.read.option("basePath",basepath).parquet(*path)
df.count()
```

the error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent
    call last) <ipython-input-321-3c9a60fd698f> in <module>()
    ----> 1 df.count() ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in
    count(self)
        453         2
        454         """
    --> 455         return int(self._jdf.count())
        456 
        457     @ignore_unicode_prefix ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in
    __call__(self, *args)    1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256        
    return_value
    = get_return_value(
    -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in
    deco(*a, **kw)
         61     def deco(*a, **kw):
         62         try:
    ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
         64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
         65             s = e.java_exception.toString() ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
    get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
        327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329             else:
        330                 raise Py4JError( Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2635.count. :
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
    Task 312 in stage 1079.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost
    task 312.0 in stage 1079.0 (TID 54105, localhost, executor driver):
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No such device or
    address     at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:163)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)  at
    java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)     at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:151)
        at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)    at
    org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.newStream(HadoopInputFile.java:65)
        at
    org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:443)
        at
    org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:401)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:106)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:133)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:404)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:345)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:128)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown
    Source)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown
    Source)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
    Source)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
    java.io.IOException: No such device or address  at
    java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)    at
    java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)  at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:156)
        ... 32 more Driver stacktrace:  at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1651)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1639)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
        at
    scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at
    scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1638)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1872)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1821)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1810)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
        at
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)    at
    org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:297)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2775)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2774)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)  at
    org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2774)  at
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor369.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
    py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)    at
    py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)    at
    py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
    py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)  at
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSError: java.io.IOException: No such device or
    address     at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:163)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195)  at
    java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:169)     at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:151)
        at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:346)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:769)    at
    org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopInputFile.newStream(HadoopInputFile.java:65)
        at
    org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:443)
        at
    org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:401)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:106)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:133)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:404)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReaderWithPartitionValues$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:345)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:128)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:182)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown
    Source)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown
    Source)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown
    Source)     at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at
    org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at
    org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at
    org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)  at
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such device or
    address     at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)     at
    java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)  at
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.read(RawLocalFileSystem.java:156)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: java.io.IOException: No such device or address - check that your path is correct

Comment: my path is correct because i still use df.show() to show data in dataframe and it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a wildcard in your path `'/mnt/raw_data/play/log_stream/playstats_v100/topic=play_map_play_vod/date=2021-01*'`, so probably one of them is corrupted. `show` doesn't throw any error that's mean the path of the records is shown basically correct, but not all of them. You can debug which one is causing the error by checking paths one by one (or few at the time)